# Jquery display multiple images in div from select/option field in form

Tags: jquery

I need some help finding a jQuery solution to display multiple images in a preview DIV from a select list of images in a form.

Example:

```
<select name="collection[]" id="collection" multiple="multiple">
   <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
Display image here, preferrably in a table/group. When the user deselects from the list the image disappears from this div.
</div>
```

I have seen this jquery script in an answer before (below), but it does not work with multiples.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#collection").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();

        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> The .val() method is primarily used to
>   get the values of form elements. In
>   the case of `<select
>   multiple="multiple">` elements, the
>   .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option.

So you just need to loop through each element in the `src` array:

```
var src = $(this).val();

// Clear the preview area first
$('#imagePreview').empty();

// Loop through all selected options
for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    $("#imagePreview").append($('<img>', {src: src[i]}));
}
```

Note that I used `$('<img>', {src: src[i]})`, which is an easier way of creating elements with dynamic attributes than joining strings together.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - works great but it is a little glitchy. Sometimes the additional images are not shown immediately in the DIV. At times, the images appear as they are added to the selection - perfect. Then, at other times it is not until an additional two images are added, that they suddenly both appear together. Not one at a time, every time. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @Jas, I'm not sure. Try putting in a `console.log` or an `alert` inside the `change` function and see if the handler is always getting triggered.

Answer (score 2):

If helpful to anyone, I built upon the solution and ended up with:

```
$("#collection").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += "<img src='" + $(this).val() + "' border='0' style='padding: 3px;' alt=\"" + $(this).text() + "\" /> ";
              });
          $("#imagePreview").html(str);
        })
        .change();
});
```

This gave me more control over the text and values in the form, and allows for more control over the img tag.